# Multithreaded use of Regex

Tags: .net, regex, multithreading, performance, thread-local

Given the following from MSDN:

> Regex objects can be created on any thread and shared between threads.

I have found that for performance, it is better **NOT** to share a `Regex` instance between threads when using the `ThreadLocal` class.

Please could someone explain why it runs approximately 5 times faster for a thread local instance?

Here are the results (on an 8 core machine):

```
   Using Regex singleton' returns 3000000 and takes 00:00:01.1005695
   Using thread local Regex' returns 3000000 and takes 00:00:00.2243880
```

Source Code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly string str = new string('a', 400);
        static readonly Regex re = new Regex("(a{200})(a{200})", RegexOptions.Compiled);

        static void Test(Func<Regex> regexGettingMethod, string methodDesciption)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            var sum = Enumerable.Repeat(str, 1000000).AsParallel().Select(s => regexGettingMethod().Match(s).Groups.Count).Sum();
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' returns {1} and takes {2}", methodDesciption, sum, sw.Elapsed);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test(() => re, "Using Regex singleton");

            var threadLocalRe = new ThreadLocal<Regex>(() => new Regex(re.ToString(), RegexOptions.Compiled));
            Test(() => threadLocalRe.Value, "Using thread local Regex");

            Console.Write("Press any key");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We appreciate you sharing information, but this isn't exactly how we do it.  A question still has to be a question.  Can you please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7585087/edit) to remove the solution, then add the solution as an answer?  Failing to do so may result in this question being closed as "not a real question."  For more information [please read this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13128/may-i-share-some-useful-code-i-wrote-on-stackoverflow) on [meta].  Thanks!

Comment: if this *does get closed*, go ahead and edit your question.  Then flag it for moderator attention and ask to have the close reason reviewed.  The mod will see my comments and reopen so that you can add your answer.

Comment: @Will, I think this is actually a valid question. Why is it faster using a `local` regex rather than a `static readonly` regex. Just needs a bit of re-wording and the actual question moved nearer to the top. Doesn't matter that it all runs on one thread which is slightly mis-leading I suppose :/ (Saying that I don't know what `ThreadLocal` class does...

Comment: @SBlackler: You miss the point.  Sergey wasn't asking a question, he was sharing information he learned.  I was letting him know how we handle it around here.  So, please, everybody chill and wait until he can answer his own question with the information he has.

Comment: @SBlackler: It doesn't all run on one thread. CPU goes to 100% on my quad-core machine when this is run. The `.AsParallel` spins up four threads to do this work.

Comment: @JimMischel, ah my bad, I didn't see the `.AsParallel` xD

Comment: @Will, on the last line it clearly says `Thread local Regex preforms 5 times faster. Why?` Is that not the question?

Comment: @Will, I edited the question to look more like a question, would you agree with it now?

Comment: @SBlackler: Yes, that was the whole point of this.  Now, SergeyS can add his solution and share his information.  Yknow, it usually isn't this hard.

Answer (score 5):

Positing my investigation results.

Let's ILSpy Regex. It contains a reference to RegexRunner. When Regex object is matching something it locks its RegexRunner. If there is another concurrent request to the same Regex object another temporary instance of RegexRunner gets created. RegexRunner is expensive. More threads are sharing Regex object the more chance to waste time creating temporary RegexRunners. Hope Microsoft will fix that addressing the era of massive parallelism.

Another thing: static members of Regex class taking pattern string as a parameter (like Match.IsMatch(input, pattern)) also must perform badly when the same pattern is being matched in different threads. Regex maintains a cache of RegexRunners. Two concurrent Match.IsMatch() with the same pattern will try to use the same RegexRunner and one thread will have to create temporary RegexRunner.

Thanks Will for letting me know how you handle here questions that topic-starter have found an answer for.